# Timing the Thrash

Tags: c++

I feel confident that my nested for conditions will thrash memory, but I would like to know long it takes.  I'm assuming time.h can help but I don't know what methods to use and how to display.  Can someone help?

I have updated my code with the suggestions made and I believe it worked.  I got a slow output of 4 (thrashTime).  Is this in seconds?  Also, perhaps my method could be refactored.  I set a time before and after the for conditions.

```
// Updated
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;
int array[1 << 14][1 << 14];

int main() {
    time_t beforeThrash = 0;
    time_t afterThrash = 0;
    time_t thrashTime;
    int i, j;

    beforeThrash = time(NULL);
    for (i = 0; i<16384; i++)
        for (j = 0; j<16384; j++)
            array[i][j] = i*j;

    afterThrash = time(NULL);
    thrashTime = afterThrash - beforeThrash;
    cout << thrashTime << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Look up `time()` and `clock()` to get started.  Your particular platform probably has a high-res timer as well.  Google will help you find it.   As for "large enough to thrash memory"?  That's just 256K bytes.  That'll thrash the L1D cache in a modern processor, but won't make the system sweat at all.  The L2 controller will just laugh.  Move that array out of `main` to file scope, and try something much larger...  If you have a 64-bit compiler, try `int array[1<<20][1<<10]`.  That's 4GB...

Comment: Once you do get your time measurement code working, try switching `i` and `j` so you increment the right most dimension in the _outer_ loop instead of _inner_ loop, and see what that does to your timing.  You might be surprised...  And one last thought:  Unless you declare your `array` as `volatile`, the whole experiment might be a tad disappointing, because the compiler could optimize your for-loops away 100%.

Comment: @JoeZ That array size was too large so I lowered it.  Thanks for the tip!  Could I have written it the same way within the for conditions?

Comment: Yes, you could have written `1 << 14` there.  I'd recommend parentheses in most places though, or assign these to `const int ISIZE = 1 << 14, JSIZE = 1 << 14`, and use `ISIZE` and `JSIZE` in place of bare constants...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just follow the instruction in [time](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/time/) and [clock](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/clock/) as Joe Z mentioned.

A quick demo for printing current time:

```
#include <ctime>
time_t start = time(0);
const char* tstart = ctime(&start);
// std::cout << tstart; will give you local time Fri Dec 06 11:53:46 2013
```

For time difference:

```
#include <ctime>
clock_t t = clock();
do_something();
t = clock() - t;
// std::cout << (float)t / CLOCKS_PER_SEC; will give you elapsed time in seconds
```

You can simply replace `do_something();` with the operations to be measured.